# I got ERROR about "Extra argument 'forKey' in call" for cache

Tags: swift

I used 'HybridCache' of "Nothing but Cache".

But This can't use for Swift4. So I change to "Storage".

And the part of code got this error massage

> Extra argument in call

These are code for loading some data.

```
    func object(for key: String) -> Observable<SwiftyJSON.JSON?> {
        return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in

            self?.cache?.object(key) { (data: Data?) in <-- Error massage for "key"
                guard let data = data else {
                    observer.onNext(nil)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                    return
                }

                Async.userInteractive {
                    let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(data: data)

                    Async.main {
                        if let error = json.error {
                            observer.onError(error)
                        } else {
                            observer.onNext(json)
                        }
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    }
                }
            }

            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

I don't know how solve it
the `cache` are this.

```
    fileprivate let cache = try? Storage(
        diskConfig: DiskConfig(name: "ReadGirl.JSONCache"),
        memoryConfig: MemoryConfig(expiry: .never, countLimit: 10, totalCostLimit: 10),
        transformer: TransformerFactory.forCodable(ofType: Data.self) // Storage<User>
    )
```

Comment: Please follow [this](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache#async-apis)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I fixied and Error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I fixied by myself.

```
self?.cache?.async.object(forKey: key) { result in
                switch result {
                case .value(let data):
                    Async.userInteractive {
                        let json = try? SwiftyJSON.JSON(data: data)
                        Async.main {
                        observer.onNext(json)
                        observer.onCompleted()
                        }
                    }
                case .error( _):
                        observer.onNext(nil)
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    }
                }
            return Disposables.create()
            }
```